# URL rewrite small issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

I try to do the following:

`http://abc.com/site/15/mike` to `http://abc.com/site/profile.php?id=15`

In the script folder I've placed the following htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)*$   ./profile.php?id=$1
```

The problem is that the file is found, but into it, the css and other files can't be found.
It considers paths like: `http://abc.com/site/15/style.css`

What could I do? I've tried so many rewritte rules that I don't know what could be there.

the ideea is that all the link from tht bage are relative t that path. all will become www.abc.com/site/15/onepage.php. So what can I do about that?

Comment: This might go better on [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why not change the URL of your CSS to an absolute one, like `http://abc.com/style.css`?

Comment: the ideea is that all the link from tht bage are relative t that path. all will become www.abc.com/site/15/onepage.php. So what can I do about that?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write your link beginning by a '/' so that the browser knows the right path ?

```
<link href="/css/myCssFile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: the ideea is that all the link from tht bage are relative t that path. all will become www.abc.com/site/15/onepage.php. So what can I do about that?

Comment: May-be I didn't understand your problem but the example link above is a relative path: making it beginning by "/" tells the browser that he will find this resource at this URI starting from the site root. (so it will look for this css file at mySite.com/css/myCssFile.css. Like that your links stay relative to your domain root.

Answer (score 0):

This should exclude urls with a . inside, such as styles.css, it that helps.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^\.]+)*$   ./profile.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new folder called `css` to be like this

```
http://example.com/site/15/css/myCssFile.css
```

or use full path like this

```
<link href="usr/www/site/15/css/myCssFile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Tell me if there's a problem